# Imagemagick convert: -strip everything *except* the colorprofile (color colour profile)

Tags: imagemagick, strip, color-profile

I'm using Imagemagick to resize large images (jpgs, pngs and tiffs) and convert to jpg for use in the browser.

I use -strip to remove all unnecessary information and keep my images nice and clean.

But in the process I'm removing colour profiles. This is really noticeable when it's an AdobeRGB 1998 image as it becomes really flat.

Is there a way to strip everything unnecessary except for the colour profile? Lots of people have asked this on forums before but I've never seen a solid answer.

Comment: Some notes on what I've explored so far: 1) use -thumbnail instead of -resize (I'm not sure if this has any other consequences), 2) just forget stripping completely, browsers are good at showing the colour profiles and extra info shouldn't be too big 3) detect the colour profile, -strip everything then put the colour profile back - but so far I haven't been able to detect AdobeRGB using imagemagick's identify.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do that other than your option 3). See %[profiles] and %[profile:icc] and %[profile:icm] at https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php or parse it from identify -verbose yourfile

Comment: Another option would be to transform all images to sRGB colourspace and then strip everything, including the profile.

Comment: Thanks guys. I haven't been able to detect Adobe RGB using imagemagick's identify (that probably requires a separate SO question!), so even converting back to sRGB isn't easy currently. But, I have actually implemented -thumbnail instead of -resize and things are looking good so far. I'm tempted to put that as the answer to this question, but I haven't had it in place long enough to trust that I haven't wrecked anything. If anyone does have a reason why -thumbnail shouldn't be the solution, please do tell me here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP here, answering my own question for anyone who needs it in the future:

I've swapped `-resize` for `-thumbnail` and have removed `-strip`. All seems good.

`-thumbnail` strips the exif data, but leaves the colour profile intact.

It *sounds* like it's just for making small images, but you specify dimensions in exactly the same way as with `-resize` so it's appropriate for any size of image.

I've had this live for about three weeks without problems so far, so happy to say this is a solid solution.